# Iteration of http requests in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, get, iteration

I am trying to make multiple http get requests in nodeJs.  I need to continue getting records until there are no more available.  I am having problems trying to do the iteration of a chunk of code. I had been reading about the async module but I am not understanding how to apply it.  Please help.

Here is the **New** code **11/25/2014**:
The step I want to repeat is the GetUrl(newBlock) is the step I want to repeat until there is no more blocks.  I determine that there is no more blocks when the result.lenght of the request response is less than 5,000.

**Is there a way of me getting this parameter pack from newBlock function and then stop the loop if I use the whilst async module?**

```
// JS Script:        GPSAPIClient
// Code Description: API client code to retrieve GPS data for customer with account number: 47631
//                   This script requires Node.Js environment installed with Request() and Node-crontab modules (through NPM).
//                   It will run (as a backend script) every minute and retrieve the GPS available.
//
// Author :          Vanessa Torres, Professional Services
var request = require("request");
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var crontab = require('node-crontab');
var csvFile = "";


var debug = false;
process.argv.forEach(function(val, idx, array) {
    if (val.toLowerCase() === 'debug') {
        debug = true;
        console.log('\n\n\n******************DEBUG MODE ACTIVE(Do not run in prod)******************\n\n\n')
    }
});

console.log('waiting to start running');


var jobId = crontab.scheduleJob('* * * * *', function() {
    //Gettting  system date and adding leading zeros when are single digits.  I need this to build the get request with date filters.


    var d = new Date();
    var nday = d.getDate();
    var nmonth = d.getMonth();
    var nhour = d.getHours();
    var nmin = d.getMinutes();

    var nfullyear = d.getFullYear();
    if (nday < 10) {
        nday = '0' + nday;
    };
    //1 minute substraction except for when is zero (the value will negative).  
    if (nmin != 0) {
        var nmin = nmin - 1;
    };
    if (nmin < 10) {
        nmin = '0' + nmin;
    };
    // added because TLC Plumbing is 2 hours behind us. (MST)
    nhour = nhour - 2;
    if (nhour < 10) {
        nhour = '0' + nhour;
    };

    var nmonth = nmonth + 1;
    if (nmonth < 10) {
        nmonth = '0' + nmonth;
    };

    var options = {
        //url: 'https://credentials@api.comettracker.com/v1/gpsdata' + '?fromdate=' + nfullyear + '-' + nmonth + '-' + nday + 'T' + nhour + '%3a' + nmin + '%3a' + '00',
        url: 'https://credentials@api.comettracker.com/v1/gpsdata?fromdate=2015-11-23T17%3a00%3a00&todate=2015-11-24T10%3a00%3a00',
        method: 'GET',
        rejectUnauthorized: !debug
    };

    function GetUrl(callback) {

        return request(options, function(error, response, body) {
            console.log('request for links');
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            var result = JSON.parse(body)['links'];
            var urlnext = result[2].href;
            console.log('UrlNext: ' + urlnext);
            console.log(result[2].rel);
            //moreBlocks = newBlock(urlnext);

            moreBlocks = callback(urlnext);
        });
        // request to get the next block of records (maximun 5,000)
    };


    // HTTP get request - 1st request
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        var result = JSON.parse(body)['gps-recs'];
        console.log(result.length);
        //console.log(result);


        //create .csv file if result.length is > = 1 (If we received GPS records)
        if (result.length >= 1 && result.length < 5000) {
            console.log('entered first if, result.length: ' + result.length);
            buildCSV(result);
        };

        //add the subsequent request when result.length = 5000

        if (result.length == 5000) {
            console.log('entered second if, result.length: ' + result.length);
            buildCSV(result);
            console.log('I came back from buildCSV.  result.length is : ' + result.length);
            **GetUrl(newBlock)**;
            //console.log('moreblocks back from newblock: ' + moreBlocks);
        };
    });
});

function newBlock(urlnext) {
    console.log('URL passed to newBlock: ' + urlnext);
    // option 2 - variables needed to built the url (like the first request)
    var n = urlnext.length;
    var rest = urlnext.substr(40, n);
    console.log('Rest: ' + rest);

    var options = {
        url: 'https://credentials@api.comettracker.com/v1/gpsdata/' + rest,
        method: 'GET',
        rejectUnauthorized: !debug
    };

    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log('nextblock request');
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        var result = JSON.parse(body)['gps-recs'];
        if (result.length == 0) {
            //no records for filter
            console.log('first if' + result.length);
            moreBlocks = false;
        };

        if (result.length < 5000 && result.length > 0) {
            //last block appends record and ends
            appendCSV(result);
            moreBlocks = false;
            console.log('second if' + result.length);
        };
        if (result.length == 5000) {
            //appends records but has to keep running
            appendCSV(result);
            console.log('third if- moreBlocks' + result.length);
        };
        console.log('moreBlocks: ' + moreBlocks);
    });

};

function buildCSV(result) {

    var csvFile = " ";
    console.log('before csvFile: ' + csvFile);
    //adding headers
    csvFile = csvFile.concat('UserNumber' + ',' + 'UserTimeTag' + ',' + 'Latitude' + ',' + 'Longitude' + ',' + 'SpeedMph' + ',' + 'Heading' + ',' + 'Status' + '\r\n');
    // loop runs result.length times
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        csvFile = csvFile.concat(result[i].UserInfo.UserNumber + ',' + result[i].UserTimeTag + ',' + result[i].Latitude + ',' + result[i].Longitude + ',' + result[i].SpeedMph + ',' + result[i].Heading + ',' + result[i].Status + '\r\n');

    };
    //console.log(csvFile);  
    fs.writeFile('file.csv', csvFile, function(err) {

        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('file saved');

    });
};



//appending additional blocks 
function appendCSV(result) {
    var csvString = " ";
    // loop runs result.length times
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        csvString = csvString.concat(result[i].UserInfo.UserNumber + ',' + result[i].UserTimeTag + ',' + result[i].Latitude + ',' + result[i].Longitude + ',' + result[i].SpeedMph + ',' + result[i].Heading + ',' + result[i].Status + '\r\n');

    };
    // console.log(csvString);  
    fs.appendFile('file.csv', csvString, function(err) {

        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Data appended');

    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see if `moreBlocks` is in the same scope as the `while`. On the other hand, the `while` statement will start making calls indefinetilly until that flags changes, and that might be too late. You need to make sure you do each subsequent request at a time.

You could use async's ´whilst´ function:

```js
var moreBlocks = true;

whilst(function(){
  return moreBlocks === true;
},function(callback){
  return request(options, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('request for links');
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    var result = JSON.parse(body)['links'];
    var urlnext = result[2].href;
    console.log('UrlNext: ' + urlnext);
    console.log(result[2].rel);

    //You NEED to make sure you update moreBlocks
    moreBlocks = newBlock(urlnext);

    // Go to next step.
    return callback(res);

  })
},{
  //You are done!
  //Call any function you'd like.
});
```

Check the docs [here](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilsttest-fn-callback)!

Edit, if `newBlock` is asynchronous:

```js
var moreBlocks = true;

whilst(function(){
  return moreBlocks === true;
},function(callback){
  return request(options, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('request for links');
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    var result = JSON.parse(body)['links'];
    var urlnext = result[2].href;
    console.log('UrlNext: ' + urlnext);
    console.log(result[2].rel);

    //Now status has the info about moreBlocks.
    return newBlock(urlnext, function(status){
      moreBlocks = status;
      // Go to next step.
      return callback(res);
    });       

  })
},{
  //You are done!
  //Call any function you'd like.
});
```

Somewhere on newBlock:

```js
function newBlock(urlnext, callback) {
      // some code..
      return request(options, function(){
        //here status decides if we are done.
        return callback(status);
      });
    }
```

Comment: I changed the code with your suggestions.  You can see it in the question (i added the code).  But it is running only 2 times.  I am still learning Javascript ( I come from legacy systems development). When you have a chance, take a look and if you can give me some light... thanks!

Comment: I see, you need to add a callback to `newBlock`, how would you know when that request is done? that way, once that happens you can call the callback inside the `whilst` function.

Comment: I'm still struggling in grasping the async.whilst loop.  Do you know any documents I can read to understand this?  Thank you for your help...

Comment: Perhaps it helps to think it this way: `whilst(a,b,c);` where *a*: block of code that runs and determins if we should run the "whilst" code, *b*: whilst code, here is the action you want to do and *c*: is what do you want to do after *a* determined you are done.

Comment: Is there a way of me getting a parameter (moreBlocks) back from newBlock function and then stop the loop if I use the whilst async module?  I think this is where my struggle comes from... I posted the new code without the whilst module yet.  Just wanted to show the exact flow of events.  Thank you!

Comment: You need to put moreBlocks in a scope that is accessible for all functions, so when you update it, all other functions are "aware". Beware that, in your example, the functions `appendCSV` and `buildCSV` are asynchronous and you are treating them as synchronous, that might give you some problems.

Comment: fixing the moreBlocks issue and the other function... too. Thanks